# #ifdef in separate header not working as expected

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have a #define in a separate header file:

```
#ifndef __sitkConfigure_h
#define __sitkConfigure_h

#define SITK_4D_IMAGES

#endif // __sitkConfigure_h
```

(full source: https://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleITK/blob/8be437486dce85da271576f866393cd54fe0f865/Code/Common/src/sitkConfigure.h.in. The define is managed by a `#cmakedefine` and turns into `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES` as expected when cmake is configured.)

As usual the header is included where the config is needed. For example:

```
#include "sitkConfigure.h"

#ifdef SITK_4D_IMAGES
/** \brief Constructor for 4D images where pixel type can be specified.
 * @{
 */
Image( unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int depth, unsigned int length, PixelIDValueEnum valueEnum );
/**@}*/
#endif // #ifdef SITK_4D_IMAGES
```

and

```
#include "sitkConfigure.h"

#ifdef SITK_4D_IMAGES
Image::Image( unsigned int Width, unsigned int Height, unsigned int Depth, unsigned int Length, PixelIDValueEnum ValueEnum )
  : m_PimpleImage( NULL )
{
  Allocate ( Width, Height, Depth, Length, ValueEnum, 0 );
}
#endif // #ifdef SITK_4D_IMAGES
```

(full source: https://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleITK/blob/8be437486dce85da271576f866393cd54fe0f865/Code/Common/include/sitkImage.h and https://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleITK/blob/8be437486dce85da271576f866393cd54fe0f865/Code/Common/src/sitkImage.cxx)

Why are the `#ifdef` not triggered by the `#define` in `sitkConfigure.h`? It is literally driving me nuts. If I put `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES` directly in the files the `#ifdef`s are triggered as expected. Further, if I write `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES 1` in `sitkConfigure.h` and `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES 2` in the other files, the compiler complains about redefinitions of `SITK_4D_IMAGES`, so it can clearly see the definition in the files from where the header is included.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.10 with GCC 4.8.9 and Mac OSX Yosemite with Apple Clang 600.0.56. You are most welcome to `git clone -b development --single-branch git://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleITK.git` to reproduce.

Made a minimal example but was unable to reproduce the bug. The issue must be with SimpleITK's build infrastructure. In case anyone is interested it can be downloaded from [dropbox.com/s/zlcnqtx32cq4q22/example.zip?dl=0](http://dropbox.com/s/zlcnqtx32cq4q22/example.zip?dl=0).

Building instructions:

```
git clone -b development --single-branch git://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleITK.git
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild
ccmake .
```

Set `SITK_4D_IMAGES` to `ON`, configure, generate and `make -j4`. The SuperBuild downloads, builds and installs all dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce code to minimal reproducible example (like it described [here](http://sscce.org/))? This way you can improve chances to get the answer. Also, please provide building instructions (with dependencies to be installed etc).

Comment: I see at least two possibilities: (1) there's another file `sitkConfigure.h` that is being included instead of the one you think is being included, or (2) there's another header that defines `__sitkConfigure_h`.  Note that the name is reserved; you should not be creating names that start with double underscore (or, indeed, a single underscore).

Comment: @SamProtsenko Building instructions added. Minimal reproducible is a great suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your suggestions, ruled out (2), (1) <del>will take some digging</del> is ruled out by compiler complaining about redefinitions. As for the double underscore, I have to follow upstream conventions :/

Comment: Slightly unusual suggestion: can you add `-DSITK_4D_IMAGES=37` on the command line.  You should then get a redefinition warning/error where your header is included (since `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES` is not the same as `#define SITK_4D_IMAGES 37`).  If that doesn't happen, then you have clear evidence that your header is not functional.  Also consider adding `#ifdef __sitkConfigure_h` / `#error sitkConfigure_h pre-defined` / `#endif` to the start of the header.  This should tell you if the file is being included more than once, or if the name is generated somehow that you haven't spotted.

Comment: Or even simply add `#error Header included` at the top of your configuration header...

Comment: Adding `-DSITK_4D_IMAGES=37` to command line does indeed produce redefinition warnings.  Adding `#ifdef __sitkConfigure_h` / `#error sitkConfigure_h pre-defined` / `#endif` throws an errors so file is included more than once. Thank you or your suggestions, will keep digging.

Comment: FYI, made a minimal example but was unable to reproduce the bug. The issue must be with SimpleITK's build infrastructure then. Anyway, in case anyone is interested it can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlcnqtx32cq4q22/example.zip?dl=0

Comment: `__sitkConfigure_h` is a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/981959) and should not be used

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, as previously discussed, that is upstream code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#ifdefs` where handled correctly by the compiler. The issue was related to the use of SWIG for wrapping the interface in Python/Java/R/Ruby/Octave/Tcl/Lua/C#. The defines were not passed to SWIG which therefore did not compile what was inside the `#ifdef`. Adding `%include "sitkConfigure.h"` to the SWIG .i file fixed the problem.